# How to get the User object from the user_key in Flask template

Tags: python, templates, flask

I have Comment objects that has a user_key property and I'm passing in the Comment objects to my Flask template, but I want to display the User.username property next to each comment, and when I'm in the template I only have the user_key. How can I get access to the user object based off the user key once I'm in the template?

Here is what my model classes look like:

```
class Base(ndb.Model, modelx.BaseX):
  created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  modified = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
  version = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=TIMESTAMP)
  _PROPERTIES = set([
      'key',
      'id',
      'version',
      'created',
      'modified',
    ])

class Comment(Base):
  user_key = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User, required=True)
  comment = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
  like_count = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=False, default=0)

class User(Base, modelx.UserX):
  name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True, required=True)
  username = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True, required=True)
  email = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True, default='')

  active = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=True)
  admin = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=False)

  federated_id = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True, default='')
  facebook_id = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True, default='')
  twitter_id = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True, default='')

  _PROPERTIES = Base._PROPERTIES.union(set([
      'name',
      'username',
      'avatar_url',
    ]))
```

Then I'm rendering the template like this:

```
  query = model.Comment.query()
  comment_dbs = query.fetch()

  return flask.render_template(
                               'filename.html',
                               html_class='classname',
                               title='Title here',
                               comment_dbs=comment_dbs
                               )
```

And finally, in the template file, this is where I'd like to have access to things like my username and the avatar properties on the user objects: (This code just prints out the user key in the spot where I'd like to put the User.username.

```
# if comment_dbs
    {% for c in comment_dbs %}
        {{c.user_key}}{{c.comment}}<br>
    {% endfor %}
# endif
```

I know that in Python I can do a key.get() to return the object I want, but is there a way to do this in the template?

Do I need to loop through the Comment objects, and then lookup the User objects based off each key and then pass in that array of User objects to the template? Seems kinda messy and that there is probably a better way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jinja2 filters](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#filters) to solve this kind of problems. There are no such [built-in filters](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#builtin-filters) for you , but fortunately it's quite easy to create [custom filters](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#custom-filters).

For a simple but not complete example:

1. Define a regular Python function which takes `user_key` as parameter to find a `User` object or `username`.

   ```
   def get_user_by_user_key(user_key):
       # your logic code here, e.g.
       username = get_username()
       return username
   ```
2. Register it on the template environment:

   ```
   environment.filters['get_name_by_key'] = get_user_by_user_key
   ```
3. Use the custom filter in template:

   ```
   {% for c in comment_dbs %}
       {{ c.user_key|get_name_by_key }} {{ c.comment }}<br>
   {% endfor %}
   ```

Answer (score 2):

@Leon's answer was correct, but I wanted to put what I ended up doing here so others could see it:

I dug around and found that there is a decorator for declaring a filter, so I did this:

```
@app.template_filter()
def get_username_by_user_key(user_key):
    user = user_key.get()
    return user.username
```